# Javascript/underscore/lodash : Comparing object in array of objects and remove the matched object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have on array of object, which looks like the following :

```
var arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    key_a : "value1",
    key_b : "value2"
  },
  {
    key_c : "value12",
    key_d : "value23"
  }
];
```

Now, I have another object :

```
 var objToCompare = {
    key_a : "value1",
    key_b : "value2"
 };
```

What are the possible ways to compare 'objToCompare' with 'arrayOfObjects' and remove the matching objects from 'arrayOfObjects' -- using javascript or underscore js or lodash?

So, the resultant array of object would look like :

```
var arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    key_c : "value12",
    key_d : "value23"
  }
];
```

*The object should only be removed from the array of objects, when all the properties are matched.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an easy way to solve your problem. Convert objectToCompare to array and using `_.differenceWith()` to compare.

Check my code below, please.

```
    var _ = require('lodash')

    var arrayOfObjects = [
      {
        key_a : "value1",
        key_b : "value2"
      },
      {
        key_c : "value12",
        key_d : "value23"
      }
    ]


    var objToCompare = {
       key_a : "value1",
       key_b : "value2"
    }

    var arrayToCompare = []
    arrayToCompare.push(objToCompare)

    var result = _.differenceWith(arrayOfObjects, arrayToCompare, _.isEqual)

    console.log(result)
```

Comment: @Medet Tleukabiluly How about my solution.

Comment: @Curious86 If you found that useful. Could you kindly upvote it please?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the _.reject and _.isEqual method. This is almost the exactly opposite of the _.where method in Underscore/Lodash.

```
let result = _.reject(arrayOfObjects, (obj) => _.isEqual(obj, objToCompare))
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't mix es6 here

Answer (score 1):

Pure javascript version

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [{
    key_a: "value1",
    key_b: "value2"
  },
  {
    key_c: "value12",
    key_d: "value23"
  }
];

var objToCompare = {
  key_a: "value1",
  key_b: "value2"
};

// credits https://stackoverflow.com/a/6713782/2308005
function objectEquals(x, y) {
  if (x === y) return true;
  if (!(x instanceof Object) || !(y instanceof Object)) return false;
  if (x.constructor !== y.constructor) return false;
  for (var p in x) {
    if (!x.hasOwnProperty(p)) continue;
    if (!y.hasOwnProperty(p)) return false;
    if (x[p] === y[p]) continue;
    if (typeof(x[p]) !== "object") return false;
    if (!Object.equals(x[p], y[p])) return false;
  }
  for (p in y) {
    if (y.hasOwnProperty(p) && !x.hasOwnProperty(p)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}


var result = arrayOfObjects.filter(function(item) {
  return !objectEquals(item, objToCompare);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as:

```
arrayOfObjects.filter((item) => !(item.key_a === objToCompare.key_a && item.key_b === objToCompare.key_b))
```

**Edit**: FWIW: This is a pure javascript solution that only does what it *needs* to and doesn't effectively recreate the lodash/underscore `isEqual`

Comment: What if in the future there gonna be a new `key_z`? That's not good solution

Comment: It was a hardcoded question. There's pros and cons to every solution. Whatever _you_ think is the ideal solution could almost certainly be called overkill depending on the context. There's not enough context in the question to give a proper _overall_ solution, but this definitely works and doesn't require extra code or libraries for a case that is unknown of if it even exists...

Comment: How about my solution?